# How to retrieve the iPhone's locale setting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, properties, operating-system

I have googled for it but I am a bit surprised that I couldn't find it.

I just want to access what locale the device has configured. I tried to find how to list all system propreties (in case I could find the locale there) but couldn't even find how to do that. I know(/think) I have retrieved the system properties before, but I also remember it wasn't easy to find that information when googling for it. Perhaps I am using the wrong words when searching...

How do I identify what locale (and/or system properties) that is configured on the actual device?

Thanks!

/Niklas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSLocale *curLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. To get the actual locale as a string I did [curLocale localeIdentifier]. Your link is pointing to OSX but it works the same for iOS.